# Vulkan: aggressive increase in memory usage when splitting one VkBuffer into two

Tags: c++, vulkan

**Setup**

I followed [this tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/) to set up a vulkan application. This is how it looks:

[image]

The source code for this stage is available [here](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/26_depth_buffering.cpp).

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to apply two different textures to the two squares. To do that, I split the two squares into separate VkBuffers (a Vertex buffer and an index buffer for each of them).

**What went wrong**

Before splitting, the memory usage floats around 120MB. But afterwards, the usage is around 230MB. I think that shouldn't happen and I'm trying to figure out why.

**What I did**

To create the buffers (take vertex buffer for example).

```cpp
  vertexBuffers.resize(vertices.size());
  vertexBufferAllocations.resize(vertices.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i != vertices.size(); i++) {
    VkDeviceSize bufferSize = sizeof(vertices[i][0]) * vertices[i].size();

    VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
    VmaAllocation stagingBufferAllocation;
    createBuffer(bufferSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT,
                 VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_CPU_ONLY, stagingBuffer,
                 stagingBufferAllocation);

    void *data;
    vmaMapMemory(allocator, stagingBufferAllocation, &data);
    memcpy(data, vertices[i].data(), bufferSize);
    vmaUnmapMemory(allocator, stagingBufferAllocation);

    createBuffer(bufferSize,
                 VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT |
                     VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT,
                 VMA_MEMORY_USAGE_GPU_ONLY, vertexBuffers[i],
                 vertexBufferAllocations[i]);
    copyBuffer(stagingBuffer, vertexBuffers[i], bufferSize);

    vmaDestroyBuffer(allocator, stagingBuffer, stagingBufferAllocation);
  }
```

The command buffer I'm using (I think this has nothing to do with the memory usage, but just in case):

```cpp
  if (vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i], &beginInfo) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw runtime_error("failed to begin recording command buffer!");
  }

  array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues{};
  clearValues[0].color = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
  clearValues[1].depthStencil = {1.0f, 0};
  VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo{
      .sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO,
      .renderPass = renderPass,
      .framebuffer = swapChainFramebuffers[i],
      .renderArea = {.offset = {0, 0}, .extent = swapChainExtent},
      .clearValueCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size()),
      .pClearValues = clearValues.data(),
  };
  vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffers[i], &renderPassBeginInfo,
                       VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
  vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                    pipeline);

  vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffers[i], VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS,
                          pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSets[i], 0,
                          nullptr);
  for (size_t j = 0; j != vertices.size(); j++) {
    VkBuffer vertexBufferArray[] = {vertexBuffers[j]};
    VkDeviceSize offsets[] = {0};
    vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffers[i], 0, 1, vertexBufferArray,
                           offsets);
    vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffers[i], indexBuffers[j], 0,
                         VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16);
    vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffers[i], static_cast<uint32_t>(indices[j].size()),
                     1, 0, 0, 0);
  }

  vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffers[i]);
  if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffers[i]) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe VMA can be a little bit too aggressive. Common strategy is to double the allocation if you are out of space. You could try manually allocating without VMA for comparison. Additionally Validation layers could use a lot; try with and without.

Comment: You could also change the default VMA block size, since you need very little memory.

Comment: @krOoze, thank you so much for the suggestions! I disabled validation layers, that didn't quite help. But when I ran it without VS debugger (I used it to view memory usage), then the usage goes down to ~90MB. So weird that VS debugger injects that amount of stuffs into the code. (Then what is the point of showing memory usage, which is incorrect anyway X.X)